# Is it possible to check in/out files from a webserver with a FF-plugin or Chrome extension?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am creating a CMS and want to know if its possible to download a folder, edit things and upload it back to the server without much user interaction.

For example just press a checkout button and the files are stored on your computer. after you are finished editing these files you press the checkin button. no selecting files again and such things.

Is it possible to access the filesystem and up/download files after a user gives you the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox - yes, add-ons have full access to the hard drive and can download/upload files. See for example [FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/fireftp/), also [code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO).

In Chrome - no, extensions are not allowed to access the hard drive, other than limited access via File System API (which is a virtual file system actually). Best you can do is including a binary NPAPI plugin into your extension and making it write to disk. Users will see lots of scary warnings when installing this extension.